# Split comma separated string table row into separate rows using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I have a query that returns the following

```
ID       SomeValue
1        a,b,c,d
2        e,f,g
```

Id like to return this as follows:

```
ID       SomeValue
1        a
1        b
1        c
1        d
2        e
2        f
2        g
```

I already have a UDF calls Split that will accept a string and a delimter and return it as a table with a single column called [Value]. Given this, How shoudl the SQL look to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tsql split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

Comment: @AlvinThompson I believe it has actually been several brazillion times ;-).

Comment: Actually that question doesn't quite answer this one. I already have a function that splits the string. What I wanted is a single query that would return the results from one table split into a second table. Anyway, answer below did the trick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use XML like so:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (1,'a,b,c,d'),
        (2,'e,f,g');

WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  ID,
            [xml_val] = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(SomeValue,',','</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM @yourTable
)

SELECT  ID,
        [SomeValue] = col.value('.','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY [xml_val].nodes('/t') CA(col)
```

Comment: This is the simplest example of using XML for this I've seen among all the various answers around this site so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You use `cross apply`.  Something like this:

```
select t.id, s.val as SomeValue
from table t cross apply
     dbo.split(SomeValue, ',') as s(val);
```

Comment: could you share the "dbo.split" function you used ?

Comment: @B3S . . . SQL Server offers one in 2016.  Otherwise, you can get them easily by Googling "SQL Server split".

Comment: well, the correct sys function to use is `STRING_SPLIT` and not `dbo.split`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: yeah `dbo.split` is usually a user defined function, in most of the implementations.  Just putting my 2-cents that in 2016, there is a system function that does what we have had to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but I wanted to add my solution so that I can find it in the future. I had to make a slight tweak to [Stephan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641928/stephan) Solution to account for values that do NOT contain a delimiter:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (1,'a,b,c,d'),
        (2,'e'),
        (3,'f'),
        (4,'g,h,i');

WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  ID,
            [xml_val] = CAST('<t>' +
                                CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX(',', SomeValue) > 0
                                    THEN REPLACE(SomeValue,',','</t><t>') 
                                    ELSE SomeValue
                                END + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM @yourTable
)

SELECT  ID,
        [SomeValue] = col.value('.','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY [xml_val].nodes('/t') CA(col)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Mark, but did you try testing my solution for values without delimiters? You'll notice that my solution accounts for that by adding at '<t>' and '</t>'  in the CAST expression so it will work regardless of there being any delimiters or not. Yours will work, but I believe it adds unnecessary work

Comment: Hmmm, I was getting an error (more than likely a data issue now I think of it) and I was pressed for time do I just need to make this work for me. I will try it again next week and let you know.